# how to take each item with all items of the right of it in a list? [scala]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

suppose I have 1d array or list as the following:

```
val a = Array(1, 5, 7, 9)
```

I want to produce a result (2d array or list of tuples) where as

```
Array[(1,5), (1,7), (1,9), (5,7), (5,9), (7,9)]
```

How can I do that in Scala?

Here is what I tried:

```
val c = for (a_ <- a; b_ <- a) yield (a_, b_)
```

The problem c now has:

```
Array((1,1), (1,5), (1,7), (1,9), (5,1), (5,5), (5,7), (5,9), (7,1), (7,5), (7,7), (7,9), (9,1), (9,5), (9,7), (9,9))
```

which is wrong result, because it is not cartesian product !

Comment: What do you mean it was not efficient? what algorithm you used? because anyway the code will have at-least O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Agreed,  you will always end up with quadratic time complexity.  You can save space though,  if you generate the array e.g. using an iterator

Comment: I mean I need to use two nested for loops. its a complex code. I wonder if it can be done using reduce function or something similar where every item can take all items in the right if it. I updated the question to show my try to make shorter and maybe better code

Comment: ygor, I agree it will be quadratic, but isn't there a way to shorten the code rather than keeping nested loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to shorten the code? Here's a one-liner.

```
a.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (n,x) => a.drop(x+1).map(n -> _)}
//res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,5), (1,7), (1,9), (5,7), (5,9), (7,9))
```

Or perhaps this.

```
a.combinations(2).map(x=>(x(0),x(1))).toArray
```

Comment: In the general case `combinations` isn't going to work because it removes duplicates and may not preserve order.

Comment: then I should use the first option: a.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (n,x) => a.drop(x+1).map(n -> _)}

Comment: Yes, or something similar using the wonderful `tails` method: `a.tails.flatMap(t => t.drop(1).map(t.head -> _))`

Comment: Thanks. That was great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it: the best I could:

```
var tmpRes: ListBuffer[List[(Int, Int)]] = ListBuffer()
(0 until itemSet.size) foreach { i =>
      val left = List(itemSet(i))
      val (_, right) = itemSet.splitAt(i+1)
      val res:List[(Int, Int)] = for (left_ <- left; right_ <- right) yield (left_, right_)
      tmpRes += res
}

var combinations: ListBuffer[(Int, Int)] = tmpRes.flatMap(x => x)
combinations.foreach(println)
```

If someone has a better solution, please do share it :)